# My likes on YouTube comments do not register

Tags: youtube, video, comments

I am not able to `Like` or `Dislike` comments on YouTube videos.

The buttons appear but when I click them there is no highlighted green thumbs up. I've tested liking a comment on one of my videos that was unlisted with a friend and it still didn't work.

I can `Like` or `Dislike` videos it just seems to be comment that are an issue.

Does anyone know what this problem could be?

Comment: Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Still having the problem?

Comment: @Bibhas yes I still am.

Comment: You see anything on the error console? Is it browser dependant?

Comment: Failed to load resource http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js
Failed to load resource http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_companion_ad.js
Failed to load resource http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22ads%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221%22%2C%22callback%22%3A%22(function()%7B%7D)%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22content%22%5D%7D%5D%7D

Comment: @Bibhas Those are the errors but that is on page load not actually when clicked. I've had this issue ever since that major YouTube change when they added liking of comments.

Comment: Is it browser specific? Or do you have the problem *anywhere* you login and try to comment?

Comment: @Bibhas No it's not. Any browser is the same, though it's not commenting it's liking and disliking comments.

Comment: Any ad blockers or cookie policies involved?

Comment: @Stephanie Yes and no. I currently do use them, but used to not use any extensions and still had the issue. I've tried multiple browsers, and with and without extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you like a comment on Youtube, unlike when you like an actual video, the like registers, but does not actually display (presumably while it undergoes security measures to ensure the like was valid). Don't worry: it is working.

Comment: A while back I tested liking a users comment who commented on one of my videos. I waited little and checked back and the comment still had no likes. This was a while back so I will try again and report back if this is true.

Comment: Okay I tested it and I do not see it appearing yet that the comment was liked. The little thumb icon highlights but I do not see that the like count has been increased.